# Is millet similar to lentils?

Tags: grains

I have not seen millet for sale in local supermarkets (Massachusetts).

What does it taste like? Does it taste similar to a lentil?

Answer (score 3):

Millet is a small sized grain, and has a pretty mild, bland flavor. Lentils are legumes, and have a little bit more flavor to them. 
To me the two things do not taste similar, but I guess that is a matter of opinion.

In some urban areas in the US, you can often find whole grain millet in food stores which have a "health food"/"organic" type orientation.

Comment: Probably the best comparison is other extremely mild grain-based things, maybe couscous or grits. It really is bland; something like cracked wheat might be too flavorful to be a good comparison.

Comment: @Jefromi : Farina? (sold as Cream of Wheat and a few other brand names).  Not flavorful, as they remove the bran